# Как отправить ответ на запрос после завершения определенной команды в Node.js

Tags: javascript, android, node.js

Я отправляю изображение с клиента Андроид на сервер Node.js, где оно обрабатывается Python программой. Я связываю Node.js с Python программой посредством пакета или библиотеки Python-Shell из NPM. Мне нужно отправить результат обработки обратно клиенту, как ответ на запрос.

Но из-за асинхронной архитектуры Node.js, ответ отправляется сразу, не дожидаясь выпонения и завершения обработки, которая занимает где-то 30-40 секунд. В результате, Андроид клиент получает пустой ответ.

К тому же, я не могу использовать `res.write()` несколько раз. После того как я использовал его однажды, я полагаю, что соединение разрывается. Поэтому у меня не получается использовать `res.write()` или `res.send()` в обработчике событий. И поэтому я накапливаю все сообщения из Python программы на Node.js сервер в отдельный массив, который пытаюсь отправить, но опять же необходимо дожидаться выполнения Python программы.

Итак, как можно отправить ответ, после того как работа программы завершится и результат будет готов для отправки? Есть ли другой способ для отправки результата работы (являющийся текстом) Андроид клиенту?

Код Node.js

```
app.post('/', rawBody, function (req, res) {
//rawBody is a function that receives chunks of image binary and creates a req.rawBody

if (req.rawBody && req.bodyLength > 0) {
    console.log("entered file writing");
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime().toString();
    var filename = 'Image'+timestamp+'.jpg';
    fs.writeFileSync(filename, req.rawBody);
    fs.writeFileSync('imagelist.txt', __dirname+ '/' + filename);
    //here I create an instance of PythonShell and execution of //testfile.py starts
    var pyshell = new PythonShell('testfile.py', options);
    //I store in the output all the messages from Python
    var output = [];
    // whenever python prints any output this event is emitted
    pyshell.on('message', function(message, error){
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(message);
            //try to write the message into response
            res.write(message);
            output.push(message);
    });

    pyshell.end(function(err) {

            console.log('python finished');
            //send response
            res.end();
            //res.send(output);
    });

    pyshell.on('error',function(err){
            console.log(err);
    });

} else {
    res.send(500);
}

});
```

Вот как я получаю ответ на Андроид клиенте:

```
            public static String boundary =  "*****";
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            //configure connection for output scp -r -P 5004 node-chat server3@crowdsensing.cs.hut.fi:/home/server3/server_nodejs
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            //for the performance reasons
            //conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            //HTTP connections may be held open longer than necessary
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setReadTimeout(50000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(50000);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

        BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


        while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            //System.out.print(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
        responseStreamReader.close();

        String response = stringBuilder.toString();
        System.out.println(response);

        in.close();
        conn.disconnect();
```

Comment: Покажите заголовки, которые принимаете в андроиде. Вероятно, такое поведение связано с Transfer-Encoding и с Content-Type, нужно правильно их указывать.

Comment: Да, забыл показать, уже добавил. Но я  не могу использовать на сервере `Node.js`  `res.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Length': message.length
                        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
                });
` , получаю ошибку `Error: Can't render headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: Посмотрите этот топик http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать другую форму вызова скрипта

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

app.post('/py', rawBody, function(req,res){
  // pre-stuff ...

  // async 
  PythonShell.run('testfile.py', { a: [], b: 'c' }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) return res.send(500);
      console.log('finished');
      res.send(result);
  });
});
```

И конечно для управления асинхронными потоками удобно использовать [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)
! Не стоит перемешивать синхронную и асинхронную логику.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не помогло. Я так понял, что дело не совсем в методе вызова `Python` программы, а в том когда отправлять ответ. Если отправлять после выполнения программы, то либо `Node.js` не отправляет, либо `Android` неверно принимает и обрабатывает. Скорее всего, ошибка в обработке запросе или заголовках запроса, которые невено указаны, только пока непонятно как это исправить